# No session found for current thread in Custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, javabeans

I'm new in Grails and I'm trying to make my own AuthenticationProvider for the security core plugin, the problem is that I'm getting the follow error when try to return the token

---

### Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

This is my AuthenticationProvider code:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString()
    def User user
    User.withTransaction {
        status ->user = User.findByUsername(name);
        if(! user.springSecurityService.isPasswordValid(user.getPassword(),password,null)){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        }

        // Here comes the problem when I try to 
        return  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities1()) ;
    }
}




    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
       return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

My bean declaration (in the resources.groovy file) is:

```
beans = {
    myCustomAuthenticationProvider (com.security.MyCustomAuthenticationProvider)    {

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure, that the `user.getAuthorities1()` call is being lazily loaded outside of the session.

You will need to initialize it before your session is closed. One solution is to replace your `User.findByUsername(name)` call with a different method that also initializes this property.

Comment: I've solved it using @Transactional in the user.getAuthorities1()  method. Thanks ddalton!!!